# Indent entire code base from project root in VIM

Tags: vim, indentation

How can I indent my entire codebase from project root directory using Vim ? I know to indent one whole file, `gg=G` in normal mode will do the job. But is there any way to indent the entire codebase with a single command ?

Answer (score 1):

First store the files in args. Use a find command that finds all relevant files

```
:args `find -name "*.c"`
```

Then execute any vim command on all arguments:

```
:argdo normal! gg=G | update
```

Comment: `normal! gg>G` should do it.

Comment: normal! gg=G then I guess :), Thanks

Comment: This does not work. I get an error
`E79: Cannot expand wildcards`
`"`find . -name" [New File]`

Comment: What platform do you use? It may not work on windows if you don't have a unix style find in your path.